# if element is not blank add another element to the list of required element before submit

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Hi all how could I insert a (if) statement to this code that if (element1) value is not blank then (element2) is required before submitting.

I'm already using a list of validated element that needs to be filled before subtitling

I would like to add a few more to that list depending on if some element are not empty.

Here's part of the code I'm not sure how or where to inset the if statement.

```
function submitBotton() {

  var tool1 = document.getElementById("OtherEquipment1").value

  if (tool1 !== '') {
    toolowner1: "Equipment Owner is required!",
  }

  var toValidate = {
    prefDate: "Date is required!",
    Person: "Name is required!",
    Loc: "Location is required!",
    Time: "Time is required!",


  };

  var idKeys = Object.keys(toValidate);

  var allValid = true;
  idKeys.forEach(function(id) {
    var isValid = checkIfValid(id, toValidate[id]);
    if (!isValid) {
      allValid = false;
    }
  });

  if (allValid) {
    addRecord();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey Yvan. Could you add some interpunction to your question? It's barely readable at the moment.

Comment: Please identify which variables represent element#1 and element#2.

Comment: "_if (element1) value is not blank_". Are you familiar with the method `isBlank()` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Comment: Im probably not asking the proper question what im triyng to get at is that if tool1 is not blank then add toolowner1: "Equipment Owner is required!" to the variable toValidate: so instead of having 4 item in my toValidate list it now as 5 hope this make sense

Comment: I am not quite sure how your question is related to Google Sheets. It looks like `tool1` is a structure element of your HTML page rather than contents from Google Sheets. Please try to rephrase your quesiton and give more context and explanation about what you are doing